# Why MS created WCF test client with limitations

Tags: .net, wcf, wcftestclient

Why Microsoft has given a tool to test WCF services which is not able to test everything that we can actually create and use.

Comment: I can understand disappointment, but this is not a constructive question

Comment: I jst wanted to know the reason behind this..Which many would be like me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are millions of different sets of combinations of settings in WCF let alone when you expand that further to your machine, networked, interop etc etc. They provide the basic and most likely to be used - if you have something specific to test, you should consider writing a small test harness yourself?

Otherwise Microsoft would have to cover a huge range of possibilities?

Comment: I agree..But why to miss very basic supports..Like I created a DataContract with a combination of int, string, string[][], arraylist to be passed......AND no machine, network etc are involved here...Why the test client is not able to test..AND moreover the error message is : We can not test because you are using a xyz contract which is not supported..Common, if not supported how can we use it in service....IT is simply a lack of tools support..

Comment: Why dont you put the actual error message you've got, I'd hazard a guess if its truly as basic a combination as you say, its more likely to be code or config based than the test tool

Comment: Error in test client is : this operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses type "DataContract name"